# Classifying cofibrations in Mor(M) where M is a model category

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

If $M$ is a model category the category of morphisms in $M$ has a model category structure where the fibrations and the weak equivalences are the levelwise fibrations and levelwise weak equivalences. I have read that a morphism $f:u\to v$ in $Mor(M)$, which is really a commutative square in $M$
\begin{align*}& \ u_0\overset{f_0}{\rightarrow} v_0\\
& \downarrow u\quad\downarrow v \\
& \  \ u_1\underset{f_1}{\rightarrow} v_1,\end{align*}
is a cofibration in this model structure if and only if $f_0$ and $u_1\cup_{u_0}v_0\to v_1$ are cofibrations in $M$. I can prove that this condition is sufficient and I can prove that $f_0$ being a cofibration is necessary but I can't show that $u_1\cup_{u_0}v_0\to v_1$ being a cofibration is necessary. If someone has a nice argument for this and wants to share it or a hint I would be happy=)

Comment: This model structure is a special case of a Reedy model structure, and the description of cofibrations is a special case of Reedy cofibrations.  Reedy model structures are explained in books by Hovey and Hirschhhorn, among others.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. I know this is written in Hovey's book but I was hoping there was a easy argument in the simple case of Mor(M). But I will have a look, maybe it's not that complicated, thanks again.